# UPDATE column on ORDER of another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If for example, the table schema is below

```
CREATE TABLE MyHits  
( 
    Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
    Sequence int NULL
);
```

Sample data:

```
Name Sequence
---- --------
Dan  
Ana
Len
```

I need to update `Sequence` column to:

```
Name Sequence 
---- --------
Dan  2 
Ana  1 
Len  3
```

How to do this? What is the query?

I prefer not to use a cursor. What I trying to achieve is set `Sequence` column based on the alphabetic order of `Name` column.

Comment: And then what do you do when you insert a new row (Aaron)? Update *all the other rows*? You might think you are optimizing something by storing this row number but you’re probably doing more harm than good. You can always generate this rank at query time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *row_number* here and an updatable CTE:

```
with t as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(order by name) rn
    from myhits
)
update t set Sequence = rn;
```